# My Spring Controller is public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> but I also want to handle redirections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am calling a method from Ajax and I am responding with

`@ResponseBody Map<String, String>`

My functionality is okay! But my problem is when the user is not logged in and is calling to this method directly by the url. In this case, I don't want my controller to answer with

`@ResponseBody Map<String, String>`

I want my controller to answer with a redirection to the login page.

I am using

`public ModelAndView`

to accomplish this state in other cases, but  I don't know how to handle this situation.

Comment: Are you using a security framework or rolling your own handlers?

Comment: Since all my controllers were simple I was not using security framework. But now I think I need to use it.

Comment: Using spring security will do the most of the work automatically.

Comment: I can redirect clients if they are not logged in before processing my ```@ResponseBody Map<String, String>``` method with Spring Security?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: And yes. You can define login and logout pages and much more security related stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone mentioned , **`Spring security is essential for this functionality`**. But if its a quick work around, you can check out [Spring boot AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

You intercept the controller call before it processes the request , and do authentication and alter the output accordingly